# How to play a sound file in sbt scala

Tags: scala, audio, sbt, wav

I searched pretty much everywhere.
How do I play sound files in a sbt project? 
All answers I found didn't work for me.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried JFugue library?

Comment: I would prefer not to use external librarys. Is there no way to play wav files without external librarys?

Comment: So as I understand you, this:
import java.awt._; Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();   doesn't generate sound?

Comment: Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep() this does work. Can u make this toolkit play a wav file?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a sbt task where execute SO command from your scala code. 
For example in Linux you can do `play soundfile.wav` so from scala you could write something like:

```
import sys.process._

"play /path/to/soundfile.wav".!<
```

In windows may be:

```
import sys.process._
"start c:\\path\\to\\soundfile.wav".!<
```

I just tested from scala repl from linux and it works.